# jsoup parsing issue with frameset and id attributes

Tags: java, jsoup, frameset

I have source code like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>SCHOOL-100</title> 
    </head>  
    <frameset rows="111, 1*" border=0>    
        <frame name=top src="top.cgi" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 noresize scrolling="no"> 
        <frameset cols="200, 1*">     
            <frame name=left namo_target_frame=right src="left.cgi" scrolling=yes>     
            <frame name=right namo_target_frame=_self src="LTE_info.cgi">   
        </frameset>         
        <noframes>         
            <body bgcolor=white text=black link=blue vlink=purple alink=red>  
                <input type=hidden id=age value="12" >  
                <input type=hidden id=class value="9" > 
                <p> </p>    
            </body>      
        </noframes>     
    </frameset>         
</html>
```

I'm fetching the data from the url. I have tried:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("mobile.testmifi/cgi-bin/frame_main.cgi").get();
Elements media = doc.select("noframes");
for (Element src : media) {
    //System.out.println("media source is ---- " + src.text());
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that I'm not able to reach after `noframe` node. I want to fetch the value of `id=age` and `id=class` . All those values are coming as string not as nodes. If I do `getElementsbyAttribute("id")` it shows null.

I need to fetch the value of age/ class (ids) using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), please help anyone, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to get the values on the client-side with jQuery or on the server-side with jsoup? Can you show us what you have tried so far and what is failing? Also, do you have control over the markup that's being emitted in your HTML source?

Comment: I m fetching the data from the url. I have tried Document doc =Jsoup.connect("http://mobile.testmifi/cgi-bin/frame_main.cgi").get();
       
       
       Elements media = doc.select("noframes");
       
       for (Element src : media) {
                  //System.out.println("media source is ---- " + src.text());
                 }

Comment: The issue i m facing i m not able to reach after noframe node. I want to fetch the value of id age and class . All those values are coming as string not as nodes. If I do getElementsbyAttribute("id") it shows null. I hope this clear your doubt..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is noframes is not recognised as a standard tag and the html inside will be treated as its value. If you just want to get the values of age and class, you could take the value of noframes tag and parse it as a body fragment and then read. For e.g.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class JsoupParser4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("mob.html"), "UTF-8");
            Document noFramesDoc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(doc.select("noframes").text());
            System.out.println("Age = " + noFramesDoc.select("input[id=age]").attr("value"));
            System.out.println("Class = " + noFramesDoc.select("input[id=class]").attr("value"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The mob.html file contains the html tag code in your question.

Comment: can you please let me know if we can get all input values without selecting "noframes" , Why Document noFramesDoc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(doc.select("body").text()); is not working. I need ti parse the input values with parsing from body.